# Why does my mouse and keyboard become disabled when my Macbook returns from sleep?

Tags: macos, macbook, sleep

I am running into problems with my Macbook running OSX 10.6.

Sometimes when my machine returns from sleep.  The keyboard and trackpad stop functioning.

I have to plug in a usb mouse and restart the machine to return functionality to my keyboard and trackpad.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume there is an issue with something in the sleep and wake code. Do you have any support contract or warranty with Apple? That would be your best bet.

Comment: Yes. I do have Applecare.  I guess I should put it to use.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having a similar problem, try an SMC reset first.

[Intel-based Macs: Resetting the System Management Controller (SMC)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964), TL;DR version:

**Resetting the SMC on Mac portables with a battery you can remove**

1. Shut down, disconnect the power adapter, and remove the battery.
2. Hold the power button for 5 seconds.

**Resetting the SMC on portables with a battery you should not remove on your own**

1. Shut down.
2. Hold left ⌃, ⌥ and ⇧ and the power button for 5 seconds.

**Resetting the SMC for Mac Pro, Intel-based iMac, Intel-based Mac mini, or Intel-based Xserve**

1. Shut down and disconnect the power adapter.
2. Hold the power button for 5 seconds.